# Need help in groovy scripting in SOAP UI Pro

Tags: soapui

Thanks in advance for any help. I tried searching the answers and I could not find a clear answer. Hence, creating a new thread.

Outline: I am trying to create an test suite in SOAP UI aiming to test all the api's involved in our application.

**Scenario:**

1. first step is to create a REST request, GET method. It gives me back response which contains 12 nodes.
2. I would need to run a REST request,'POST' method for each of the nodes.

**Issue:** I am stuck in the second step. I could think of the logic needed but I am not very sure with the code.

Logic I thought:

1. Create an array and get each node's values as an item
2. Create a loop with the number of items in the array as upper limit
3. Assign each node's values as input properties to the post method

It would be of much help if anyone could help me out with groovy script for this.

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/data-driven-tests/functional-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a little detail on what the nodes contain but I've done very similar things.

You actually may not even need a groovy script if the node is just a parameter for the post request.

Your step structure would be something like

1. GET Request Data Source
2. GET request
3. POST Request Data Source (JSON/XML option)
4. POST request
5. Any additional stuff
6. Loop back to POST request data source
7. Loop back to GET request data source

This is assuming your structure is something like

```
<GETResponse>
  <node>
    <nodeValue1>1</nodeValue1>
    <nodeValue2>2</nodeValue2>
  </node>
  <node>
    <nodeValue1>3</nodeValue1>
    <nodeValue2>4</nodeValue2>
  </node>
</GETResponse>
```

Step 3 you just need to set up with the row being each node. And the column being whatever values you need from the nodes.

Please comment if this does not fit your use case